# What dataset are used for tests in Caffe?

Tags: caffe

When I run,

`caffe test` or `caffe time`

the tests proceed even for the newly imported network architectures. What data is used for those tests?

Update:

Here is a snippet from the data layer from the Caffenet, where there is no reference to source. It comes from:
https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/models/bvlc_reference_caffenet/deploy.prototxt

```
name: "CaffeNet"
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Input"
  top: "data"
  input_param { shape: { dim: 10 dim: 3 dim: 227 dim: 227 } }
}
```

Update 2:

But still the following command works and runs the test, despite the fact we are using `deploy.prototxt`:

```
caffe test -model=models/bvlc_reference_caffenet/deploy.prototxt -weights=models/bvlc_reference_caffenet/bvlc_reference_caffenet.caffemodel
```

Comment: look at your net: what is the input layer and where it points to?

Comment: @cerebrou, I think you are mistaken. For testing, you would use: https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/models/bvlc_reference_caffenet/train_val.prototxt (note the data layer with "include { phase: TEST }", this has the source).

Comment: deploy.txt also doesn't have a loss function, which is needed for testing. It just gives the predicted probabilities.

Answer (score 2):

As @Shai suggested, you need to look at the input layer, as defined in the prototxt.

Since you don't give any details about your models, I will use the interfaces tutorial as an example:
http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/interfaces.html

which has the following:

```
caffe test -model examples/mnist/lenet_train_test.prototxt -weights examples/mnist/lenet_iter_10000.caffemodel -gpu 0 -iterations 100
```

You can find this prototxt here:
For example:
https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/mnist/lenet_train_test.prototxt

The data source (that is included for testing) is given as:

```
source: "examples/mnist/mnist_test_lmdb"
```

This is the data that is used.

You can read about how to download this data in the `examples/mnist` directory:

https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/master/examples/mnist

Update: if the Data layer doesn't have a source parameter, then it is likely just used for "deployment". In this setup the data can be passed to the model live without the ground truth data. `caffe test` should not be called on this type of prototxt. Look for the training/testing prototxt instead (most models come with both).